# Deferred Execution - Dictionary output

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a Linq Query that returns about half a million rows. However, since I have not called ToList(), the execution is still deferred. So far so good.

I need a `Dictionary<int, List<DateTime>>` output from this query which would return about 100,000 entries (Distinct integer column values) in the Dictionary.

I tried something like this ...

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<DateTime>>();

var myDictionaryOutput = MyQuery.Select(p => AddOrUpdateDictionary(myDictionary, p));
```

Where MyQuery is my linq query and AddOrUpdateDictionary is a custom function I wrote.

This projects each entry to a Dictionary which is not what I want.

I want just the dictionary output.

The sample data looks as follows ...

```
1234 | 2015-08-24 | 2015-08-25 | null       |
1234 | null       | 2015-08-26 | null       |
2345 | null       | null       | 2015-08-23 |
```

I want the output to be a Dictionary with two keys

(2 Keys from 3 rows <=> 100,000 keys from 500,000 rows),

```
1234 -> List<DateTime>{2015-08-24, 2015-08-25, 2015-08-26}
and 
2345 -> List<DateTime>{2015-08-23}
```

My thoughts are evaluating MyQuery.ToList() and passing it to my Custom function will not be very efficient as I would then have to loop through half a million rows using ForEach for example.

Am I wrong or is there a better way to achieve what I am after?

Comment: It's not clear what the shape of your data is, nor how you're trying to pick the 100K entries from the 500K rows in the result...

Comment: Seems like you should take a look at `GroupBy` operator

Comment: Thank you Jon, that was instantaneous reply. I have updated my question with some additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is a group by with filtering `null`s, and subsequent conversion to dictionary:

```
var dict = MyQuery
    .Select(row => new {row.Id, Dates = new[] {row.Date1, row.Date2, row.Date3}})
    .SelectMany(row => row.Dates.Select(d => new {row.Id, Date=d}))
    .GroupBy(row => row.Id)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(r => r.Date).ToList());
```